# Find the 33rd two characters, and where they belong

Tags: computer-puzzle

I'm working on a puzzle.  I'm about 75% of the way through solving the puzzle.

The only thing left is you hash 33 two character pairs.  I have 32 two character pairs.

Possible characters are [a-z, A-Z, 0-9]

Positionally the 33rd two character pair can be at the beginning, in between every other pair, or at the end.

Once a 33 two character pair is generated.

My programming skills are so rusty, that this one is causing me brain cramps.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oh, you cheater... it's D5 for a reason!

Answer (score 2):

> Certainly not elegant, but [Give it a go](https://repl.it/@rshields/CaringImmediateMass)

The result is

> **11aD1wwya0dCV4fkL01oDy0YeYY7qIXHn**, which is made by adding **6e** to the end. The hash it produces is the first one.